# Dropdownlist doesn't grab correct ID to display data in form

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2017

This is my first time to try SEARCH function for c# exercise with Postgres.

I try to use dropdownlist to select student records and display in form.  But It doesn't grab the ID from dropdownlist correctly to retrieve correct data and display in form.  Is there any logic arrangement in syntax that arranging wrongly?

```
connection.ConnectionString = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_student";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
txtFname.Text = row["f_name"].ToString();
txtLname.Text = row["l_name"].ToString();
txtIC.Text = row["ic"].ToString();
}

connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot `WHERE` condition in your select command.
It should be something like

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_student WHERE ID = @ID";
```

I never use Postgres before but the exception most likely implies that Postgres doesn't have implicit convert mechanism. Therefore, I suppose you need to cast the type yourself.

Modify

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
```

To

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt, ParameterName = "@ID", Value = Int64.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value) });
```

Comment: I tried to use this and it successfully retrieved correct record into form.  Thanks for the tip!
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value )));